# Can I use react-native for developing maps app

Tags: android, ios, performance, react-native, mobile

I have a question regarding possibility to uses react-native library for developing the app (ios/android) which will able to support to works with google/apple maps [put points, measure distance, etc]
So, the main question is react-native good choice for developing the app with this functionality or instead of this I should use native lang such as (swift/java) ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use react-native for developing maps app. I am currently developing a service provider app that uses google maps and I am using all features that you have mentioned above and many more i-e direction api, calculating EAT, drawing routes etc. Every thing works fine with react-native. You can follow this article **[Integrating Google Maps into React Native App on Android](https://medium.com/@samil.mehdiyev/integrating-google-maps-into-react-native-app-on-android-40c984c0e4f2)** to integrate maps feature in you app.

I am using the following libraries:

**[react-native-google-places](https://github.com/tolu360/react-native-google-places)**

**[react-native-maps](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps)**

**[react-native-maps-directions](https://github.com/bramus/react-native-maps-directions)**

Comment: thank you. I've just read the article it's very helpful. Could you say me please do you use google maps on ios devices? is it possible?

Comment: Yes, you can use google maps in ios, there are two options we can either use apple maps in ios or google maps and I am using google maps.